# WooCommerce Bookings - Reserve Resource Avaliability For Products

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce

So I offer the following products:

- Training courses which are taught over multiple days. These training courses are also not very frequent and as such there may only be one a week.
- Salon treatments which there are usually many slots over each day.

These courses and salons can be taught in multiple locations and at the moment I have these set up as “resources”. However, this is where my problems start.

The training courses are scheduled well in advance. So when a training course is scheduled, I don’t want another training course or salon treatment to be booked at that location for the relevant dates. However, in order for me to achieve this, I currently would have to:

1) Set at the resource level the dates that aren’t available for the other products using the resource.

2) Then on the product I want to be booked on that date, set the product availability as available to override the resource availability.

However, this then has a problem. Because this then also means that the product is available to be booked at other locations which isn't correct.

So essentially what I want to do is “reserve” the availability of a product inside a resource even when a booking hasn’t actually been taken for it.

So for example, if I have a training course taking place over four days next week, I would want to enter the date when the course will take place at that location and then have the whole block unavailable for any other training courses or salon treatments. This would then mean that if I needed to cancel a training course, I would just remove the date of the course from the product. Once that is done, then that time can then be booked by other products.

So then the final result I would want to have is a resource where it is mainly for salon treatments but where there are then days which would not be available because of training courses. In addition, then for the training courses, they would just have the dates when they are running and all of the other dates would be unavailable as they are reserved for salon treatments. New dates for training courses can then be added as needed.

I hope this explains more about what I’m trying to achieve. Any pointers to regards to how I can achieve this would be appreciated.